# How to construct a FunctionalJava TreeMap?

Tags: java, functional-programming, treemap, functional-java

I'm just starting to use the FunctionalJava library and wanted to make use of the immutable TreeMap. However I can't figure out how to create an empty one to start with when using a user defined class or interface.

```
fj.data.TreeMap<IAddress, Optional<ScanNode>> nodes = TreeMap.empty(Ord<IAddress>);
```

All the examples use predefined types like Ord.stringOrd. I'm totally not understanding how to create the proper Ord<IAddress>.

Could someone explain how to do this?

Thanks, Derek

Answer (score 3):

Essentially a tree-map has to have some sort of an ordering on its elements, so you must describe how to order your IAddress.

for example, lets say IAddress has 2 strings and an int (city, street, number), you could do the following:

```
// translate an IAddress to a P3 containing the important data
F<IAddress, P3<String, String, Integer>> toP3 = new F<...> () {
        P3<String, String, Integer> f(IAddress addr) { 
              return P.p(addr.getCity(), addr.getStreet(), addr.getNumber());
}

main () {
    // first map IAddress to a P3 using the function above, then simply order it by its fields
    Ord<IAddress> addrOrd = Ord.P3Ord(Ord.StringOrd, Ord.StringOrd, Ord.IntOrd).comap(toP3);

    fj.data.TreeMap<IAddress, Optional<ScanNode>> nodes = TreeMap.empty(addrOrd);
}
```

co-mapping means it first applies the function toP3 on the IAddress, getting back the P3, and then ordering it with the given P3 order.

Comment: of course, if you dont really mind about the ordering, you could always use something like Ord.<IAddress>hashOrd() or Ord.<IAddress>hashEqualsOrd()

Comment: Wow, that's pretty ugly to look at. I didn't see any mention of hashOrd() or hashEqualsOrd() in the docs. They're probably sufficient for my needs.

Comment: TreeMap is mostly useful because it gives you ordered iteration of the data. If you don't need that, you might be better off using HashMap

Answer (score 0):

If `IAddress` implements `Comparable`, you can also use `Ord.<IAddress>comparableOrd()` to construct an `Ord` for it.